# css animations created by javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a div with a css3 animated timer in it when a button is pressed. heres the code: http://jsfiddle.net/arcco96/y5nov6rz/1/. For some reason it will not create the div. I think the code should be functional but I am not sure whether or not one can create a div with a css animation after the page load.

My fiddle is based on this one: http://jsfiddle.net/zbGCq/118/.

I am creating the div with:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'timer',
}).appendTo('#center');
jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'mask',
}).appendTo('#center');
});
```

Any thoughts?

thanks

p.s. on a slightly unrelated note will I be able to overlay content on the #timer or will that be impossible?

Comment: the javascript works fine to create the divs, it's the CSS that's mesed up.

Comment: the css works too but when the js creates the div it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess your browsers work differently to mine. and both the javascript and CSS are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to jquery objects before they existed.

the css is still broken in my firefox, but the javascript is working,

It does something animated in chromium, I don't know if that's the effect you want or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbuseo9j/

```
var cv = $('.container').width();
$('.head').css({
    'height': (cv / 3) + 'px'
});

$("#btn1").click(function () {
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        class: 'timer',
    }).appendTo('#center');

    var cw = $('.timer').width();
    $('.timer').css({
        'height': cw + 'px'
    });

    jQuery('<div/>', {
        class: 'mask',
    }).appendTo('#center');
});
```

Comment: thank you ill hack around with it from here

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by animating `svg`'s `path` element through JavaScript.

You can set the `width` and `height` of the timer by changing the `width` variable. You can also change the animation speed through the `t` variable.

<kbd>**[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/ZYpxNX/)**</kbd>

```js
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var width = 150;
svg.setAttribute('width', width);
svg.setAttribute('height', width);
var t = 5;
var theta = 0;
var radius = svg.getAttribute('width') / 2;
timer.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

(function animate() {
  theta += 0.5;
  theta %= 360;
  var x = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
  var y = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
  var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
  timer.setAttribute('d', d);
  setTimeout(animate, t)
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
  <path id="timer" fill="lightseagreen" />
</svg>
```