# Centering two circles in a non-table layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, geometry

I have two circles one is an svg and the other a styled link. The styled link sits on top of the svg. The circle link must be centered both horizontally and vertically on the svg. I have come really close by positioning it dynamically with javascript.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arcco96/pf76Laux/3/ (Press start to see it in action)

The jquery eventually writes this on the document:

```
<svg id="svg">
   <path id="timer" fill="#66ff66" />
 </svg>

 <a class="round-button"><p>Ok</p></a>`
```

If you check out the code you will see that the circles are not centered.

If you can fix this or have any thoughts about this I'd like to hear them.

thanks

Comment: Hah that code looks familiar.

Comment: Yes, @chipChocolate.py he asked the z-index question earlier, right?

Comment: @Godisgood - No, I had [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27666168/3905567) it on one of his posts yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `'top': (top + 8) + 'px', 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': (-widthOf / 2) + 'px',` when you set the CSS properties of `.round-button`.

Additionally, add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.round-button` in your CSS.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/pf76Laux/7/)**</kbd>

```js
var cv = $(window).width();

function createTimer(widthOf) {
  var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
  var width = widthOf;
  svg.setAttribute('width', width);
  svg.setAttribute('height', width);
  var t = 5;
  var theta = 0;
  var radius = svg.getAttribute('width') / 2;
  timer.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

  (function animate() {
    theta += 0.5;
    theta %= 360;
    var x = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
    var y = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
    var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
    timer.setAttribute('d', d);
    setTimeout(animate, t)
  })();
}

function createButton(widthOf, top, left) {
  $('<a>', {
    class: 'round-button',
  }).appendTo('#container');

  $('.round-button').css({
    'height': (widthOf) + 'px',
    'width': (widthOf) + 'px',
    'top': (top + 8) + 'px',
    'left': '50%',
    'margin-left': (-widthOf / 2) + 'px',
    'font-size': (widthOf / 3) + 'px',
  });

  $('<p>', {
    text: 'tap',
  }).appendTo('.round-button');

}

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  createTimer(.8 * cv);
  var ml = (.25 * cv) / 2;
  var mt = (.05 * cv) / 2;
  createButton((.75 * cv), mt, ml);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: skyBlue;
  text-align: center;
}
#svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: green;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}
.round-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #464646;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.round-button p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.round-button:focus {
  background: #262626;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="svg">
    <path id="timer" fill="#66ff66" />
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="btn1">start</button>
```

Comment: @user2444319 - I've updated it, the problem was you are adding `5px` border to `.round-button` in your CSS.

Comment: it still seems off center vertically