# CSS draw a pie circle that shows progress, with 0% being a transparent circle, and 100% being a opaque circle

Tags: css, transparency, geometry, pie-chart

I am using background-image and linear-gradient to draw the pie

```
pie {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
}

.ten {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(126deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/7PtEm/

Which works great, but I want to make it so the circle is transparent at 0%, and will fill until 100% will be entirely opaque.

If I set the transparency on `pie` it just makes the filled parts transparent as well.  How can I make it so only part of the circle is transparent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is exactly what you are looking for ----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/27666168/3905567

Comment: That's great, thanks!  Quick question if you can answer, how does the animate function get called?  I'm new to web dev-- I'm assuming it has something to do with the entire function enclosed in parens, but I can't tell through these fiddle apps